# angular2-meteor refresh time 30-60s is it normal

Tags: angular2-meteor

I tried to test `angular2-meteor` project, but any change that I made on the client directory takes about one minute for page refresh. Even small change in html file that should not cause re-transpiling all js. What causes such a big performance issues? The `Angular2-seed` project refreshes and transpiles data almost immediately

Is it common for angular2-meteor that it takes so much time to reload content?
If so is it possible for example to develop angular2 app in different environment than meteor and then migrate it.

I'm using the meteor 1.3 on Windows 10. And default config that angular2-meteor bootstrap offers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7253

It looks like it may have been fixed in 1.3.4